# Using setContentPane() method correctly

Tags: java, jframe

I have created a java program in which i have used the `setContentPane()` method on a JFrame. My problem is that the frame does not get updated by the new panel immediately but gets updated upon resizing the frame.

In my program the size of the JFrame is 600,600.

To temporarily avoid this problem, after the `setContentPane()` method , I have applied a set of 2 statements:-

```
Frame.setSize(601,601);
Frame.setSize(600,600);
```

This resizes the frame and brings it back to its original size without showing much change to the user. This is working good and the panel is getting updated.

My question is, am I making any mistake and there is some other way to do it? Or I can continue using this trick? Please answer if there is any other(right) way to do it.

Comment: Just call repaint() on the frame after setting the new Content Pane...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The proper way to swap contents is to use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and let java swap/repaint for you.

Comment: Don't change the size of the frame, just call the `validate()` method of the frame.

Comment: Like all dynamic update issues, call revalidate and repaint on the container been update (or invalidate, validate if revalidate is unavailable) followed by repaint

Comment: @ahoxha- Do you mean to say that I simply need to add a statement  -Frame.validate() - after the statement setContentPane() statement?